# Templates inferring type T from return type

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have a template as follows:

```
template <class T>
vector<T> read_vector(int day)
{
  vector<T> the_vector;
  {...}
  return the_vector;
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
vector<int> ints = read_vector(3);
vector<double> doubles = read_vector(4);
```

Is it possible for C++ templates to infer the return type from when they're called, or should I just pass a dummy argument to the template with the type I want to the vector to have? The latter works but is messier.

Comment: No, in this case, you need to specify the type `read_vector<int>`. The compiler cannot deduce on return type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <vector>

struct read_vector
{
    int day;
    explicit read_vector(int day) : day(day) {}

    template <typename T, typename A>  
    operator std::vector<T, A>()
    {
        std::vector<T, A> v;
        //...
        return v;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ints = read_vector(3);
    std::vector<double> doubles = read_vector(4);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f990eac59b3790e)

Comment: Very clever, +1.  Would mind explaining it a little though for people who might not know exactly why this works as it does?

Comment: Is the allocator parameter `A` needed for this to work?

Comment: @GillBates partly yes, otherwise it will default to `std::allocator<T>`, and lead to a deduction failure when a target type uses a different allocator

Comment: This has an (easibly fixable) flaw. Standard doesn't really guarantee that `std::vector` is a template of two parameters.

Comment: @SergeyA even if so, why should the conversion operator deduce any additional parameters, if they are not usable by mortals ?

Comment: Your conversion operator won't work if vector has, for example, 3rd template argument.

Comment: @SergeyA it will, why shouldn't it ?